# How to find all Mondays in two date ranges

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, dayofweek

I and trying to get a list of all Monday dates within a range of dates the use inputs. I have got most of it working just haven't been able to figure out the for next loop on how I can add the Mondays between start date and end date and put them into a list box.

This is not home work just something I was working on with a friend trying to teach him a little more about VB as I am new to it as well.

This is what I have as of now.

```
Private Sub btnCountMondays_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCountMondays.Click
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    startDate = txtStartDate.Text
    endDate = txtEndDate.Text
    txtDaysBetween.Text = DateDiff("d", startDate, endDate)

    For monday As Integer = 0 To Val(txtDaysBetween.Text)
        If monday = 1 Then
            lstResultsBox.Items.Add()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Once you find the first monday, just repeatedly add `+7` days to that date until your end-date.

Comment: Also avoid implicit conversions from text to `Date` (`DateTime`) values, use `DateTime.ParseExact` where possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to do it using for loop you can do it as follows

```
Private Sub btnCountMondays_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCountMondays.Click
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    startDate = CDate(txtStartDate.Text)
    endDate = CDate(txtEndDate.Text)
    Dim nDays As Long = DateDiff("d", startDate, endDate) + 1
    For i As Long = 1 To nDays
        If startDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday Then
            lstResultsBox.Items.Add(startDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))
        End If
        startDate = startDate.AddDays(1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you This is exactly what I was looking for, works perfectly. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

To get list of date for all mondays day between 2 dates. Get the rage of dates.and get day of the week during looping

```
Dim dt1 As New DateTime(2012, 5, 1)
Dim dt2 As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim ddl As New List(Of String)()
While dt1 < dt2
    Dim dow As DayOfWeek = dt1.DayOfWeek
    'enum
    Dim str As String = dow.ToString()
    'string
    If str.ToLower() = "monday" Then

        ddl.Add(dt1.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))
    End If


    dt1 = dt1.AddDays(1)
End While
```